# scroll once and smoothly scroll next div on top of the other

Tags: javascript, css, html

I would like to create the same effect like on this website: https://www.razorfish.com

i've already set the item on top with the following css:

```
#first-block{
   position:fixed;
   top:100px;
   width:760px;
   margin-left:-380px;
   left: 50%;
   z-index: -99;
 }
```

How can I achieve the effect like on the website. Do I need to use js or can I just handle it with css.

I thought to listen to a first scroll on the page with js and then add an css class with transition effect.

Does anyone now how to proceed or is it a correct way to listen to the first scroll and add class with transition effect?

Comment: are you looking for something like [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#secondPage)?

Comment: Yes indeed. Great script. you can see the result on http://centralgardens.kuduclients.be/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using CSS transform property to the background image.

```
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1);
```